# Find duplicates rows on MySQL for multiples values

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have been working on this query for days. I have also checked the others related questions on this forum. I would appreciate a little help. My table contains the following attributes:

```
User_ID | Questions | Answers
```

Each User has 3 questions and 3 answers.

My objective: find all the Users that match other users on all 3 Questions and Answers. This is what I have tried: ** Self Join**

```
Select t1* from MyTable t1 JOIN (Select t2.Questions, t2.Answer FROM MyTable t2 GROUP BY t2.Questions, t2.Answer Having Count(*)>1) u on u.Questions = t1.Questions AND u.Answer = t1.Answer;
```

The query works fine but It's not what I would like to have. I feel that I am missing a little thing :)

Regards,

Comment: Can you show us a sample with Input, output and expected output?

Comment: For sure, here is what I have

Comment: I can not see any data?!

Comment: I am trying to edit it clearly on the forum

Comment: Do not add it as answert add it to your question using the edit function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the overlap between two users by using a self-join and aggregation.  The only other piece is making sure that the overlap covers exactly three questions:

```
select m.user_id, m2.user_id
from mytable m join
     mytable m2
     on m.question = m2.question and
        m.answer = m2.answer and 
        m.user_id < m2.user_id
group by m.user_id, m2.user_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: I am trying your suggestion Gordon, I will be back soon to let you know how it goes,  Thank you

Comment: The last two days, I have tried to run your query but for a reason I don't know it's taking forever. I believe that the syntax is correct but the query keeps running without any results for hours- I have created index in the attributes I used in the join but  it's still same result.  Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have a composite index on `question, answer, user_id` ?

Comment: No, I have created an index for each of them except "answer" -- I tried but it says in the error message that it is a character. My RAM is 8 GB. I  increased innodb size to 6.2

Answer (score 0):

I'll call your table Quiz. Does this work?

```
select q1.User_ID, q2.User_ID
from
    Quiz as q1 inner join
    Quiz as q2
        on      q1.User_ID < q2.User_ID
            and q2.Questions = q1.Questions and q2.Answers = q1.Answers
group by q1.User_ID, q2.User_ID
having count(*) = 3
```

I don't really know much about optimizing MySQL queries but perhaps this will help:

```
select q1.User_ID, q2.User_ID
from
    Quiz as q1 inner join
    Quiz as q2
        q2.Questions = q1.Questions and q2.Answers = q1.Answers
group by q1.User_ID, q2.User_ID
having q1.User_ID < q2.User_ID and count(*) = 3
```

Comment: I just realized that I have basically duplicated Gordon's answer.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I have tried that. I just edit my answer with Gordon about the results I got from this query.